# php mail() function with attachment sending file can't open

Tags: php, html, forms

i have created mail() function with attachment in php.the image or pdf are attached and send to like xyz@gmail.com ,the file attachment is received ,but i didn't open the file.please check my code and tell me...

html code:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <label>Email: </label>
 <input type="text" name="to" placeholder="To" >
 <br> <br>
 <label>Message:</label>
 <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
 <br> <br>
 <label>Upload:</label>
 <input type="file" name="image" >
 <br> <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

php code:

```
$file_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$attachments='';
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
{
    $path=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path); 
    $attachments=$path;
}
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"" .$attachments. "\"\n\n";
$to=$_POST['to'];
$msg=$_POST['msg'];
$file=$_POST["image"];
$body="this msg auto generated";
if(mail ($to,$msg,$body,$headers,$file))
{
    echo 'Email sent successfully!';
}
else
{
    die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
}
```

Comment: Use PHPMailer or another existing library which supports this already. This code is no where near what you're looking for I'm afraid.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: i need some clarificaton in my code..please answer